# Form input not changing when using react-testing-library on redux-form

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux, redux-form, react-testing-library

I am trying to test that when a user inputs text into an `input` that a `button` changes from `disabled` to `enabled`. It clearly works in the browser, but I can not get the test to pass. I am using `redux-form` and `react-testing-library`. However, if I use a native `input` rather than `redux-form`'s `Field`, the test passes.

I created a [repo](https://github.com/jpangelle/redux-form-sandbox) with minimal code to duplicate the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are not using the reducer from redux-form in your tests, its props will not be passed down to your component correctly. It's best if you provide a reducer which resembles what your app is actually using. The following code works.

```js
import React from "react"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import { combineReducers, createStore } from "redux"
import { reducer as reduxFormReducer } from "redux-form"
import { fireEvent, render } from "@testing-library/react"
import SimpleForm from "./SimpleForm"

// Create a reducer that includes the form reducer from redux-form
const reducer = combineReducers({
  form: reduxFormReducer,
})

const store = createStore(reducer)

it("test that button is not disabled when input is entered", () => {
  const { getByLabelText, getByText } = render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <SimpleForm />
    </Provider>,
  )

  const input = getByLabelText("Name")
  const submit = getByText("Submit")

  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "test input" } })

  expect(submit).not.toBeDisabled()
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! How would I initialize other `redux` state pieces in my store?

Comment: I'd recommend that you import in your tests the reducer your app is using while running. You can see an example of this in the docs https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-redux. The philosophy of this library is to make your tests that closely resemble how the web page is used https://testing-library.com/docs/guiding-principles, which also means your global state (reducer). 

On a side note, you might also want to take a look at other form libraries since redux-form has been loosing traction for some time https://matwrites.com/redux-form-is-dead/

Comment: This is great !